# Aligning a DIV Vertically and Horizontally in the center, without overlapping the header and footer

Tags: html, css, alignment

This is my first post on stackoverflow (go easy on me) This may be a long, over explained post. Please forgive me, i have never been good at getting my words across easily.

Basically, my page includes 5 divs...

- `#wrap` - contains all other elements
- `#header` - the header
- `#main` - this contains the #imgcont div
- `#imgcont` - this contains an image
- `#footer` - the footer

Now, my `#footer` is locked to the bottom of the page, even when re sized. This is a feature i NEED to keep. the `#imgcont` is the div i need aligning both vertically and horizontally. It basically needs to "float" in the center of the page without overlapping or underlapping the `#header` and `#footer` when resized.

The problem i am having is aligning the `#imgcont` div vertically within the `#main` div, without making it overlap or underlap the `#header` and `#footer`. The code i am using at the minute is:

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #999;
} 
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
}

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    margin-top: -32767px;
}
#imgcont {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #FC3;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Obviously, this only aligns my `#imgcont` horizontally, but i did find a code on the internet which makes the effect work when the window is fullsize or larger than the height of the `#imgcont`...

```css
#imgcont {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #FC3;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

...but when the window is made smaller, the `#imgcont` starts to overlap the `#header` and underlap the `#footer`.

I need the `#imgcont` to 'lock' to the header and footer when they meet, and then just stay aligned horizontally.

Can anyone please give any insight, im pulling my hair out! :(

I hope i have explained this well enough for you to understand, as i barely even understand it myself!

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Comment: post your html structure too

Comment: Or better, make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net so others can test.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UqsLP/

this is what i have so far. everything working as it should apart from the vertical alignment

Answer (score 0):

You need to **fix** the height and width of the body.For eg.

```
.body {   
height: 900px;
width: 1000px;
 }
```

Comment: The height of the body based on the content and the browser height. I don't think that we should fix the body height with CSS.

Comment: without fixing the body(width,height) the divs will overlap when resizing the window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Srinivas. If i use the code i pasted 1st, the page resizes fine with no overlaps. The footer stops moving when it reaches the #imgcont. It is only when i use the second piece of code (to make the #imgcont align vertically) that the divs begin to overlap each other

Comment: jsfiddle.net/UqsLP 

this is what i have so far. everything working as it should apart from the vertical alignment